# parallel assignment performance in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, performance, swap

Setting up a temporary variable to swap two elements in array seems to be more efficient than using parallel assignment. Can someone help explaining?

```
require "benchmark"

Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report do
    40000000.times { array[1], array[2] = array[2], array[1] }
  end
end

Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report do
    40000000.times do
      t        = array[1]
      array[1] = array[2]
      array[2] = t
    end
  end
end
```

Results in:

```
   user     system      total        real
   4.470000   0.020000   4.490000 (  4.510368)
   user     system      total        real
   3.220000   0.010000   3.230000 (  3.255109)
```

Comment: Erik Michaels-Ober mentions it in his talk as 40% faster but not why - https://youtu.be/fGFM_UrSp70?t=30m11s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parallel assignment creates a temporary array, which it afterwards splats.

```
GC.disable

def with_temp
  a = 1
  b = 2

  t = a
  a = b
  b = t
end

def with_parallel
  a = 1
  b = 2

  a, b = b, a
end

before_all = ObjectSpace.each_object(Array).count
with_temp
after_with_temp = ObjectSpace.each_object(Array).count
with_parallel
after_with_parallel = ObjectSpace.each_object(Array).count

GC.enable

puts after_with_temp - before_all          # => 1
puts after_with_parallel - after_with_temp # => 2
```

The one extra `Array` comes from `ObjectSpace.each_object(Array).count` itself.

---

Another way to verify - look at the instructions:

```
puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile("a = 1; b = 2; t = a; a = b; b = t").disasm
puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile("a = 1; b = 2; a, b = b, a").disasm
```

> == disasm: @>==========
>   local table (size: 4, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1, kw: -1@-1, kwrest: -1])
>   [ 4] a          [ 3] b          [ 2] t
>   0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
>   0002 putobject_OP_INT2FIX_O_1_C_
>   0003 setlocal_OP__WC__0 4
>   0005 putobject        2
>   0007 setlocal_OP__WC__0 3
>   0009 getlocal_OP__WC__0 4
>   0011 setlocal_OP__WC__0 2
>   0013 getlocal_OP__WC__0 3
>   0015 setlocal_OP__WC__0 4
>   0017 getlocal_OP__WC__0 2
>   0019 dup
>   0020 setlocal_OP__WC__0 3
>   0022 leave

---

> == disasm: @>==========
>   local table (size: 3, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1, kw: -1@-1, kwrest: -1])
>   [ 3] a          [ 2] b
>   0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
>   0002 putobject_OP_INT2FIX_O_1_C_
>   0003 setlocal_OP__WC__0 3
>   0005 putobject        2
>   0007 setlocal_OP__WC__0 2
>   0009 getlocal_OP__WC__0 2
>   0011 getlocal_OP__WC__0 3
>   0013 **newarray         2**
>   0015 dup
>   0016 expandarray      2, 0
>   0019 setlocal_OP__WC__0 3
>   0021 setlocal_OP__WC__0 2
>   0023 leave

Comment: could you improve your answer with instruction sequences, or something?

Comment: "The parallel assignment creates a temporary array, which it afterwards splats." – That's what the language specification says *should* happen. However, any Ruby implementation is free to *not* do this, provided that the user cannot observe the difference. I know for a fact that JRuby optimizes away the intermediate `Array`, and I believe Rubinius and IronRuby do, too. I suspect, Topaz and MagLev may eliminate it as well. I guess JRuby+Truffle does so, too. YARV doesn't, but then again, YARV is well known for being slow and not performing any optimizations whatsoever, so it's no surprise.